# Autolayout issue, height of two views

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, autolayout, xib

I have two  views. Both are siblings to each other. But one view is longer than the other and the smaller view is on the top of the longer view.

I want to add a constraint so the position of the smaller view is dependent of the size of the smaller view (lets say when when app runs on different iphone screens).

For example if the height of the longer view is 100, then the small view should start from 60, and if the longer view height is 200 then the smaller view should start from 120.

But the height of smaller view should remain fixed; I want only the position to be changed.

Comment: If the smaller view is fixed in height, it isn't 60% of the longer view. Only the positioning will differ. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Add a constraint between the views saying that the position of the smaller view should equal the position of the longer view (NSLayoutAttributeTop), and use a multiplier of 1.6

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this, @madu?